# Why is there an NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, loops

I keep on running into a problem with `NumberFormatException`. There is a problem with the `readLine` since I am reading the wrong line at the wrong time. I am writing a program which takes in that amount of money a person has and then calculates how much they will have after they gift some money to other people.

The entire problems can be found at the link below.

http://train.usaco.org/usacoprob2?a=RX1a1QYsOyX&S=gift1

```
    BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("gift1.in"));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("gift1.out")));

    int ppl = Integer.parseInt(f.readLine());
    out.println(ppl);

    HashMap<String, Integer> name = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
    String[] names = new String[ppl];
    for(int i = 0; i < ppl; i++ ){
        String n = f.readLine();
        names[i] = n; 
        name.put(n, 0);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ppl; i++){
        String person = f.readLine(); 

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
            int mon_lost = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            int ppl_given = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());



        name.put(person, (mon_lost%ppl_given)-mon_lost); 

        for(int j =0; j< ppl_given-1; i++){
            name.put(f.readLine(), mon_lost/ppl_given);
        }   

    }
    for(int i = 0; i < ppl; i++){

        out.println(names[i] +" "+ name.get(names[i]));
    }
    f.close();
    out.close();
```

Comment: There is no possible way that line input performance is your problem.  How do you know it is "taking too long"?  Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the `BufferedReader`. You can read millions of lines per second with `BufferedReader.readLine()`. It's your code.

For example, the `f.read()` calls are not correct. They will deliver character values, not digit values, and from the next line, without consuming the line terminator, so you will get a blank line next `readLine()`, so you will be totally out of sync with your input.

Basically your code doesn't even work yet, so timing it now is futile.

Comment: That was a mistake on my part, I copied the wrong code. But even without the `f.read` call, it still is taking too long.

Comment: It fails almost instantaneously when I run it, with a `NumberFormatException for input string "dave"`.

Comment: That is what I don't understand. Since it shouldn't be reading `dave` and should be reading the next line after that.

Comment: What **I** don't understand is how you can possibly be conflating a `NumberFormatException` with a performance problem. Your question is rubbish. Please debug your program, and come back with *working* code, *if and when* you *really* have a performance problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your first for-loop is probably testing with the wrong value.

Instead of :

```
for(int i = 0; i < ppl-1; ++i ) {
```

try using:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ppl; ++i ) {
```

[UPDATE]

Since you are looping too few times in this loop, the subsequent loop will be using the remaining input data inappropriately. For example, `ppl_given` would be some garbage number, which could be very big.

Comment: @EJP. No, that error would cause the subsequent loop to read data inappropriately. For example, `ppl_given` would be some garbage number, which could be very big.